# Why do pdf/image exports fail with OpenLayers Bing layers?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.6

When I try to export a print composition it generates a 0kb file. Is not possible to open this file.

It happened the same with export as image option.

The print composition model is coming from a .qpt file created with QGIS 1.8.

The problem is not in the print composition created with QGIS 1.8. I have the same problem starting with a new composition. The print works regularly if I hide the two maps in the print composition. I can print all the elements that are not maps.

The maps are coming from OpenLayers plugin/bing

What shoud I check to solve it?

Comment: Do the exports work if you start from an empty composer rather than the 1.8 template? I don't have an old template to try but it's probably fastest to recreate the template than try to look for work-arounds.

Comment: I have the same problem starting with an empty composer.

Comment: @underdark Is there a way to read the logs file to find more info?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and caused by the OpenLayers plugin: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11073

There currently is no good way to print OpenLayers laers using composer. The only workaround is to use Project | Save as image to save the current map view to a .png, load that, remove the OpenLayers layer and then use the composer.

Comment: That is not so useful :(. There are any update on it?

Comment: Any update on it?

Comment: Any updates would be in the related ticket. I don't have any more info.